# Get File using relative path play framework 2.2 java

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

I'm trying the following to create a File:

```
java.io.File myFile = play.Application.getFile("/public/myFiles/myFile.txt");
```

which is causing the error:

```
non-static method getFile(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

how do use the getFile method to return what I want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getFile` isn't a static method so you need to reference it from an instance of `Application`.

This should work to get you the current `Application` instance:

```
Play.application().getFile(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you're looking for Play 2.4:

```
import play.Environment;
...

@Inject
private Environment environment;

...
//usage
environment.getFile("file/path/relative/to/project");
```